# WPF binding with StringFormat doesn't work on ToolTips

Tags: wpf, binding

The following code has a simple binding which binds the Text of the TextBlock named MyTextBlock to TextBox's Text and ToolTip property using the exact same Binding notation:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock">Foo Bar</TextBlock>
    <TextBox    Text="{Binding ElementName=MyTextBlock, Path=Text, StringFormat='It is: \{0\}'}"
             ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=MyTextBlock, Path=Text, StringFormat='It is: \{0\}'}" />
</StackPanel>
```

The binding also uses the [StringFormat property introduced with .NET 3.5 SP1](http://blogs.msdn.com/llobo/archive/2008/05/19/wpf-3-5-sp1-feature-stringformat.aspx) which is working fine for the above Text property but seems to be broken for the ToolTip. The expected result is "It is: Foo Bar" but when you hover over the TextBox, the ToolTip shows only the binding value, not the string formatted value. Any ideas?

Comment: I wasn't able to get either of the suggested solutions below to work, but this one did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498649/wpf-binding-stringformat-not-formatting

Answer (score -8, accepted):

The following is a wordy solution but it works.

```
<StackPanel>
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=., StringFormat='The answer is: {0}'}">
    <TextBox.DataContext>
      <sys:Int32>42</sys:Int32>
    </TextBox.DataContext>
    <TextBox.ToolTip>
      <ToolTip Content="{Binding}" ContentStringFormat="{}The answer is: {0}" />
    </TextBox.ToolTip>
  </TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

I would prefer a much simpler syntax, something like the one in my original question.

Comment: @Shimmy: "better" is in the eye of the beholder, and it's alright to mark your own question the accepted answer

Comment: @Shimmy Even worse, his answer includes a '42' joke.

Comment: @Andomar, better is what folks decide with their votes, also particullary here, it's almost just the same answer. making ppl answer your questions then copy their answers and gain reputation for it is a completely wrong atitude.

Answer (score 171):

ToolTips in WPF can contain anything, not just text, so they provide a ContentStringFormat property for the times you just want text. You'll need to use the expanded syntax as far as I know:

```
<TextBox ...>
  <TextBox.ToolTip>
    <ToolTip 
      Content="{Binding ElementName=myTextBlock,Path=Text}"
      ContentStringFormat="{}It is: {0}"
      />
  </TextBox.ToolTip>
</TextBox>
```

I'm not 100% sure about the validity of binding using the ElementName syntax from a nested property like that, but the ContentStringFormat property is what you're looking for.

Comment: I see, I thought ToolTip is just a plain string as in Windows Forms. And yes, ElementName syntax in this case can not access the outer element.

Comment: Note that the {} is required only when you place the {0} at the beginning of the string, so you need it to distinguish from the other xaml markups.

Comment: Mind = blown.  I just hit this and was like "waaaat?"

Comment: It really brassed me off that stringformat doesn't 'just work' when no converter is specified. I had to write my own stringformatConverter. MS dropping the ball again...

Comment: `ElementName` cannot be used here, nor can `RelativeSource` (with an `AncestorType`), it seems when I tried. So, how can this be bound to anything meaningful at all?

Comment: This solved my problem with formatting of a Button content. Other examples I found just uses `StringFormat` withing the `Binding` and don't mention anything about difference between content controls and other controls.

Comment: `StringFormat` will only be applied when the `TargetType` is type of string. `ToolTip` Content is of type `object`.

Answer (score 27):

It could be a bug.
When you use short syntax for tooltip:

```
<TextBox ToolTip="{Binding WhatEverYouWant StringFormat='It is: \{0\}'}" />
```

StringFormat is ignore but when you use expanded syntax:

```
<TextBox Text="text">
   <TextBox.ToolTip>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding WhatEverYouWant StringFormat='It is: \{0\}'}"/>
   </TextBox.ToolTip>
</TextBox>
```

It works as expected.

Comment: The most accurate answer.. Thanks!

Comment: This is missing a comma after WhatEverYouWant to compile

Answer (score 5):

As Matt said ToolTip can contain anything inside so for your you could bind a TextBox.Text inside your ToolTip.

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock">Foo Bar</TextBlock>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=MyTextBlock, Path=Text, StringFormat='It is: \{0\}'}">
        <TextBox.ToolTip>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <Binding ElementName=MyTextBlock Path="Text" StringFormat="It is: {0}" />
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </TextBox.ToolTip>
    </TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Even you can Stack a grid inside the ToolTip and layout your text if you want.

Answer (score 3):

Your code can be as short as this:

```
<TextBlock ToolTip="{Binding PrideLands.YearsTillSimbaReturns,
    Converter={StaticResource convStringFormat},
    ConverterParameter='Rejoice! Just {0} years left!'}" Text="Hakuna Matata"/>
```

We'll use the fact Converters are never ignored, unlike StringFormat.

Put this into **StringFormatConverter.cs**:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace TLKiaWOL
{
    [ValueConversion (typeof(object), typeof(string))]
    public class StringFormatConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(value, DependencyProperty.UnsetValue))
                return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
            return string.Format(culture, (string)parameter, value);
        }

        public object ConvertBack (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Put this into your **ResourceDictionary.xaml**:

```
<conv:StringFormatConverter x:Key="convStringFormat"/>
```

Comment: While I would have preferred the top answer, the ElementBinding issue tripped me up.  This answer worked for my case where the others did not.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, you can use relative binding:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock">Foo Bar</TextBlock>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=MyTextBlock, Path=Text, StringFormat='It is: \{0\}'}"
             ToolTip="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
</StackPanel>
```