# wpf - binding stringformat on label using string literal

Tags: wpf, xaml, string-formatting

I've binded the tooltip of a slider control to it's Value property and i'm trying to use StringFormat to make it display "Current Value {0} of 10" where the {0} is the Value property.  Below is one of the various things I tried when trying to figure this out.

```
<Slider.ToolTip>
  <Label>
    <Label.Content>
      <Binding StringFormat="Current Value {0} of 10"
               ElementName="DebugLevelSlider"
               Path="Value" />
    </Label.Content>
  </Label>
</Slider.ToolTip>
```

I am having issues finding examples online of how to use stringformat with string literals such as mine above. I see a lot of stringformat date/time/currency format conversion. I think I have a way to do this with a multibinding but it just seems like an extra amount of work than necessary. I hope that for string literal formatting I still do not have to write a custom converter.

In my app I find myself using a lot of extra labels next to items so getting an understanding in the stringformat will hopefully let me eliminate some of those unnecessary labels.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For the ToolTip, you can check out [WPF binding with StringFormat doesn't work on ToolTips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197095/wpf-binding-with-stringformat-doesnt-work-on-tooltips).

As far as the StringFormat you specified above, you have to escape your string.

```
StringFormat="{}Current Value {0} of 10"
```

Here are a bunch of StringFormat examples.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2008/05/19/wpf-3-5-sp1-feature-stringformat.aspx

Comment: I still can't get the binding to work on the Value property of my slider but it works when I bind the tooltip to the variable that the slider is bound to. Maybe Value isn't a bindable slider property..hmm

Answer (score 97):

`Label.Content` is object so you can't use `Binding.StringFormat` there as the binding's target type must be `string` in order for it to work.

Two work arounds are:

1. Use `TextBlock` instead of `Label` and bind the `Text` property.
2. Use [Label.ContentStringFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contentstringformat.aspx) i.e.

   ```
   <Label ContentStringFormat="Current Value {0} of 10" Content={Binding ...} />
   ```

You only need to escape the `string` with `{}` if your first character is a `{`

Comment: Dates can be formatted within here like so: "Start Date: {0:dd-MM-yyyy}"