# How to format string for tooltip in DataGridTextColumn in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Currently I need format the tooltip string in data cell column type `DataGridTextColumn`

Here is my try:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
   <DataGridTextColumn Header ="Count Number">
      <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
         <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
             <Setter Property="ToolTip" 
                  Value="{Binding CountNumber, StringFormat={}{0:00}}">
             </Setter>
          </Style>
       </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
       <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
          <Binding Path="CountNumber" StringFormat="{}{0:00}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
        </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
   </DataGridTextColumn>

  <!-- other columns-->
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

I also tried:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
       <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
           <Setter Property="ToolTip"  Value="{Binding CountNumber}"/>
           <Setter Property="ToolTip.ContentStringFormat" Value="{}{0:00}"/>                
       </Style>
 </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
```

But both them don't work. 
For example, the number `3` should be display as `03`. Is there any idea?

Comment: If there are unusual or complex string formatting requirements, I have been using a value converter (with formatting hints passed in via the ConverterParameter attribute) *or* setting the string image in the VM.

Comment: @GarryVass  a converter or string formatted property in ViewModel should make sense, but the problem is I can't touch any source code. They said I can only edit XAML file, against my will.

Comment: What a horrible thing to impose upon someone!  Anyway, it means you will have to spec up the full tooltip template in Xaml.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="260" Header="MySample">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}">
                <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                    <ToolTip>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Age, StringFormat=0\{0\}}" />
                    </ToolTip>
                </TextBlock.ToolTip>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498649/wpf-binding-stringformat-not-formatting/5980834#5980834) is a description of this trick. Quote:

> A ToolTip is a content control, which means it doesn't really have a display model. Since the TextBox is designed to display text, the StringFormat binding property works as advertised. Button is another example of this. (Both derive from ContentControl).

The idea is to `StringFormat` earned in `ToolTip`, you need to set the `ContentControl` with `TextBlock`:

```
<TextBlock.ToolTip>
    <ToolTip>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Age, StringFormat=0\{0\}}" />
    </ToolTip>
</TextBlock.ToolTip>
```

The main thing to you is to set the force `ContentControl` in the `ToolTip`, not necessarily, as in my example (with `DataGridTemplateColumn`).

Comment: So the `DataGridTextColumn` can't work for this case? Do I have to use `DataGridTemplateColumn ` ?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with a `DataGridHyperlinkColumn` that I didn't want to change to a `DataGridTemplateColumn` so I came up with what I think is an even better solution.  All you have to do is break out the setting of the `Value` in your `<Setter...>` and put the content in a `TextBlock` like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header ="Count Number">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CountNumber, StringFormat={}{0:00}}" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
    <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        <Binding Path="CountNumber" StringFormat="{}{0:00}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
    </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```