# Don't show multi binding tool tip when empty or null

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, tooltip, multibinding

I'm assuming the reason this isn't working is because my triggers are checking for an empty string or null, yet what I really have is a textblock with a Text property that is empty (or null). Does anyone know how I can easily modify my triggers to make this happen? I've messed around for a half hour trying different ways of binding/triggers/datatriggers, with no luck.

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
   <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">

      <Setter Property="ToolTip">
         <Setter.Value>
            <!--Can't be directly in tool tip, cuz tool tip is object. StringFormat will only work with string-->
            <TextBlock>
               <TextBlock.Text>
                  <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}ID: {0}&#x0a;X: {1}&#x0a;Y: {2}">
                     <Binding Path="MyClass.Id"/>
                     <Binding Path="MyClass.x"/>
                     <Binding Path="MyClass.y"/>
                  </MultiBinding>
               </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
         </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>

      <Style.Triggers>
         <Trigger Property="ToolTip.Content"  Value="{x:Static System:String.Empty}">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
         </Trigger>
         <Trigger Property="ToolTip.Content" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
         </Trigger>
     </Style.Triggers>

   </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/a/197130/620360. And your Text will never be null or empty if your FormatString contains additional text.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I need to bind to multiple properties. Well what's strange is when the properties (id,x,y) I'm binding to above are null, the ToolTip shows a blank space. I only want the ToolTip to show when the ToolTip contains text.

Comment: I've tried your scenario in a sample app and I only get a blank space ToolTip if something is wrong with the binding. If one or all properties are null they are missed but the format text will be displayed. That's why I think your approach will not work. In my opinion simplest solution would be an additional string property for ToolTip binding returning not null if there is something to display.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, they helped me realize that I'm trying to access a property on an object that is null. I didn't post the full snippet, so that's on me. Updated my post to show where im accessing the object in my xaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I actually kept the style above exactly the same. It seems like the problem was that when my "MyClass" object is null, an empty tool tip is displayed.

But when "MyClass" is null, I really want the tool tip to stop showing.

I get around this with the following datatrigger:

```
  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=MyClass}" Value="{x:Null}">
     <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{x:Null}" />
  </DataTrigger>
```

The other triggers I had in my original post are no longer needed. By setting `ToolTip` to null in the snippet above, the tool tip will automatically not show.