# How to add text + binding in a tooltip WPF c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, tooltip

I'm trying to show a tooltip on a control where it will display the tooltip text as something like

> Total number of students in class X is stdCnt

where `stdCnt` is a int property in the VM which I want to bind.

I've tried doing it like `ToolTip="{Binding stdCnt, StringFormat='Total number of students in class X is :\ {0}'}"` but it only shows the `stdCnt` value in the tooltip and not the other text.

How do I do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/197130/3137337

Answer (score 0):

You can put other controls in the ToolTip, for example, in this case, you can use a TextBox and bind the necessary variables to its individual parts. You might get something like this:

```
<!-- Your control here -->
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip>
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="Total number of students in class "/>
                <Run Text="{Binding ClassName}"/>
                <Run Text=" is: "/>
                <Run Text="{Binding SudentsCount}"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </ToolTip>
    </TextBlock.ToolTip>
</TextBlock>
```

and yet, it's probably not worth shortening variable names like you did